# Como hago este salto con CSS?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Lo que quiero es que cuando el TAG se salga del contenedor, se ponga en la línea de debajo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este caso el TAG "PRUEBA" debería ir debajo de los que tiene atrás.

Este es el código que tengo:

```
<div className={styles.video_details}>
  <div className={styles.video_title_duration}>
    <p>{video.title}</p>
    <p>{`${video.duration} min`}</p>
  </div>
  <div className={styles.video_tags}>
    {video.tags !== ""
      ? video.tags.split(" ").map(tag => <p>{tag}</p>)
      : ""}
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.video_details {
        background-color: rgba(231, 41, 134, 1); //$primary_regular40 sin transparencia;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    
        .video_title_duration {
            align-items: center;
            height: 50px;
            width: 100%;
            @include secondary-caption;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-around;

            p:first-child {
                width: 70%;
                white-space: nowrap;
                text-overflow: ellipsis;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
        }

        .video_tags {
            display: none;
        }
    }

    &:hover {
        transform: scale(1.3);
        z-index: 2;
        
        .video_bg {
            opacity: 1;
        }

        .video_details {
            height: 90%;
            opacity: .9;
            @include flex_column_justify_space_between;

            .video_tags {
                @include flex-row;
                padding: 20px;
                width: inherit;
                

                p {
                    background-color: $gris300;
                    margin-left: 10px;
                    border-radius: 8px;
                    padding: 5px 10px;
                    opacity: 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Anotación: los TAGS solo se ven cuando se hace hover sobre la tarjeta.

Comment: Faltaría incluir qué es `flex-row`. Me imagino que es algo que añade `display:flex` y `flex-direction:row`, pero es por confirmar. En cuyo caso, la solución probablemente sería añadir un `flex-wrap: wrap`.

Comment: Si, efectivamente flex-row aplica esos dos estilos al contenedor

Comment: ¿Entonces funcionó lo de poner `flex-wrap: wrap`?

Comment: Disculpa, se me olvidó, sii, efectivamente era eso lo que le faltaba, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por defecto, cuando usas Flexbox, los elementos no se *colapsan* o mueven a la siguiente fila, sino que se siguen en la dirección indicada ajustando su tamaño para entrar dentro del contenedor, o directamente excediéndolo si no pueden disminuir más el tamaño.

Para hacer que los elementos salten a la siguiente fila (o columna si estás usando `flex-direction: column`), debes indicarlo usando la [propiedad `flex-wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap) con el valor `wrap`. Así es como se haría en el código que compartes (reducido):

```css
              /* ... */
           
              .video_tags {
                @include flex-row;
                flex-wrap: wrap;
                padding: 20px;
                width: inherit;

                /* ... */
```